# Shorten get/setValue()

Tags: java

I know that java doesn't support operator overloading and that I can make method name shorter.
But is there any other way to shorten some expressions like:

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.setValue(2);
int a = obj.getValue();
```

and make it close to this:

```
obj = 2;
int a = obj;
```

Comment: `int obj = 2;` then `int a = obj;` works, right ?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: You can pass the value in the constructor, and that's probably the shortest you can get.

Comment: @Michael yes right sorry, edited. @Iluvatar you are trying to put a `MyClass` object inside an `int`, what do you expect ?

Comment: Short answer is no,  you cannot. You could write a method that sets the field and returns the set value. But that still would require the new .

Comment: @Rafalon Re-read the question maybe. It's fairly clear to me what he means.

Comment: I don't see the application for that either...

Comment: "And what if I have a somekind of list structure and I what somthing shorter than listObj.add(5)" - then you need to use another language.

Comment: Seriously, if "listObj.add(5)" is too long for you, you are doing something terribly wrong. Mind that you can use also [addAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-).

Comment: You could learn a different JVM language that does support what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

The "best" you can do in terms of brevity is not use getters and setters and just make the field public. This is a bad idea, though: it breaks encapsulation, but I guess no more so than a getter/setter pair.

```
MyClass
{
   public int foo;
}

MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.foo = 2;
int a = obj.foo;
```

If you wanted it especially short, you could use short (aka bad) field names:

```
MyClass
{
   public int a;
}

MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.a= 2;
int a = obj.a;
```

**OR** - and I would have thought this would be obvious - use shorter function names:

```
MyClass
{
   private int foo;
   public int a() { return foo; }
   public void b(int newFoo) { foo = newFoo; }
}
```

I recommend that you **don't** write any code which follows any of these suggestions.

---

In response your edit,

> And what if I have a some kind of list structure and I what something
>   shorter than listObj.add(5)

**You don't**. There is *nothing* to optimise here. There are technically ways in which you could make that method name shorter but why would you want to? *It's three characters*.

Answer (score 0):

You can compress

`MyClass obj = new MyClass(); 
obj.setValue(2);`

to

`MyClass obj = new MyClass(2);` if you create an constructor for MyClass like

```
public MyClass(int value) {
    setValue(value);
}
```

but I dont know a shorter version.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the Variable **public** you can acess it linke this:

```
class A{
    public int x;
}
```

And here is the way to access:

```
A a= new A();
a.x = 500;
int xy = a.x;
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend public fields. And even if you did use it, your usage example also has 3 lines. So there is no improvement to the original with a private field. In fact I would consider the original better than your suggestion.

Comment: Hi!<br>I never use public variables...<br>He wish to have an shorter access way. Thats what i gave him.

Comment: But it is not shorter though.

Answer (score 0):

Shorter is not better! Get the logic right and use names that are long enough to be useful. Don't worry; you aren't likely to sprain a finger on longer names.

Names like `obj` and `MyClass` are simply terrible. They tell nothing about the domain role of the constructs. Names need to be meaningful. They should reflect the role, not the implementation.

People have to maintain your crap. Don't obfuscate your code.

Answer (score -1):

If your object only contains a primitive such as `int` you might as well just use the primitive directly.

```
 int obj = 2;  // although obviously "obj" is a bad name now!
 int a = obj;
```

If for some reason you need it to be an object, you could use the corresponding wrapper class e.g. `Integer`:

```
 Integer obj = Integer.valueOf(2);
 int o = obj.intValue();
```

But since Java provides *autoboxing* to automatically convert between primitives and their official wrapper objects:

```
 Integer obj = 2; // auto-boxing wraps the int in an Integer
 int a = obj;     // auto-unboxing extracts the int from the Integer
```

If you want to define your own class (and this can be a good idea, for example, to enforce type constraints), you could set with a constructor rather than a setter method:

```
 Age age = new Age(42); // I assume I don't need to explain how to write the constructor
 int a = age.value(); // You could call it getValue(), but unless you need a bean, why?
```

This last example is the only one I've given that works for a `value` that's a object rather than a primitive. It's quite an expressiveness and conciseness win when used in factory methods:

```
// With setter
public Age getAge() {
     Age age = new Age();
     age.setValue(currentYear - yearOfBirth);
     return age;
}

// with constructor parameter
public Age getAge() {
     return new Age(currentYear - yearOfBirth);
}
```

If you do this, you could *also* provide a `setValue()`, but if you choose not to, you have an *immutable object*, which has many benefits (about which it's easy to find articles by searching).

---

If you're looking for something similar in spirit to e.g. Groovy's operator overloading, whereby `list << item` is equivalent to `list.add(item)` -- Java has nothing similar to this.

Comment: @Michael an example of what? I can only answer the question as given.

Comment: @Michael in order for `obj = 2` to be a meaningful imaginary substitution for `obj.setValue(2)`, it must be a wrapper object with exactly one settable field. That's what I've answered.

Comment: 60% of your answer talks about primitives and autoboxing which I don't think is relevant. The fact that MyClass holds an int rather than a Foo is incidental.

Comment: @Michael if OP didn't want an answer about `int` then they shouldn't have asked about `int`. Primitives are a special case, so if you ask about a primitive, you get an answer about primitives. I have broadened it out with the first sentence.

Comment: @Michael although I find it hard to imagine many uses for a class with exactly one `getter` whose value is another object type. Why wouldn't you use that underlying object directly?

Comment: @Michael I don't know what you are complaining about. slim gives possible ways for int *and* non-Int case. You simply cannot do *exactly* what OP wants. So I guess there won't be a "perfect" answer. And nothing he suggests is wrong ... so I don't see why it should deserve -1.